# gradle nexus using self signed certificate

Tags: java, maven, gradle, nexus, java-17

I'm using gradle build system.

My maven repo is condigured liked this

```
maven {
    allowInsecureProtocol = true
    url 'https://nexus.local.intranet/repository/maven-releases/'
    credentials {
        username ''
        password ''
    }
}
```

The maven repo is a nexus behind a nginx.

I get this error from my

```
> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

When I opening the url in the browser it's working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Self signed certificat must be stored in java keystore like this:

Download certificat from server:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect nexus.local.intranet:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/local.intranet.crt
```

Import into keystore

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias local.intranet -file /tmp/local.intranet.crt
```